# Riot API With Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, riot-games-api

I trying to use the Riot API for Champions in this code

--Service

```
@Injectable()
export class ChampionService {

private riotUrl = 'https://br1.api.riotgames.com/lol/static-
data/v3/champions?api_key=myApiKey';
constructor(private _http: Http) { }
getChampion(): Observable<Champion[]> {
    return this._http.get(this.riotUrl)
        .map((res:Response) => <Champion[]>[res.json()])
        .do(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)));
}}
```

-- Component

```
export class ChampionListComponent{
errorMessage: string;
champions: Champion[];
constructor(private _ChampionService: ChampionService){}
ngOnInit():void{
  this._ChampionService.getChampion()
            .subscribe(champions => this.champions = champions,
                       error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);}
```

--HTML

```
<table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor='let champion of champions'>
                    <td>{{champion.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{champion.name}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

In the console that's appears correctly.. but nothing happen with my table

--- My Console Show This 
`Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
champion-list.service.ts:18 [{"type":"champion","version":"7.8.1","data":{"Jax":{"id":24,"key":"Jax","name":"Jax","title":"o Grão-Mestre das Armas"},"Sona":{"id":37,"key":"Sona","name":"Sona","title":"a Mestra das Cordas"},"Tristana":{"id":18,"key":"Tristana","name":"Tristana","title":"a Artilheira Yordle"},"Varus":{"id":110,"key":"Varus","name":"Varus","title":"a Flecha da Vingança"},"Fiora":{"id":114,"key":"Fiora","name":"Fiora","title":"a Grande Duelista"},"Singed":{"id":27,"key":"Singed","name":"Singed","title":"o Químico Louco"},"TahmKench":{"id":223,"key":"TahmKench","name":"Tahm Kench","title":"o Rei do Rio"},"Leblanc":{"id":7,"key":"Leblanc","name":"LeBlanc","title":"a Farsante"},"Thresh":{"id":412,"key":"Thresh","name":"Thresh","title":"o Guardião das Correntes"},"Karma":{"id":43,"key":"Karma","name":"Karma","title":"a Iluminada"},"Jhin":{"id":202,"key":"Jhin","name":"Jhin","title":"o Virtuoso"},"Rumble":{"id":68,"key":"Rumble","name":"Rumble","title":"a Ameaça Mecânica"},"Udyr":{"id":77,"key":"Udyr","name":"Udyr","title":"o Andarilho Espiritual"},"LeeSin":{"id":64,"key":"LeeSin","name":"Lee Sin","title":"o Monge Cego"},"Yorick":{"id":83,"key":"Yorick","name":"Yorick","title":"Pastor de Almas"},"Kassadin":{"id":38,"key":"Kassadin","name":"Kassadin","title":"o Andarilho do Vazio"},"Sivir":{"id":15,"key":"Sivir","name":"Sivir","title":"a Mestra da Batalha"},"MissFortune":{"id":21,"key":"MissFortune","name":"Miss Fortune","title":"a Caçadora de Recompensas"}...`

someone can help me ? Sorry for the long post

Comment: Where do you log to the console?

Comment: console.log Added

Comment: Can you try `{{champion?.id}}` ?

Comment: `<td>{{champion?.id}}</td>` same thing

Comment: How about changing the subscribe to `.subscribe((champions) =>{ console.log(champions);this.champions = champions;},
                       error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);}` what does it log?

Comment: now in the log appears it in addition   `[Object] 0: Object    length:1 
   __proto__: Array(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you are setting your response in an array:

```ts
.map((res:Response) => <Champion[]>[res.json()])
```

This still means that your array just contains one object, that contains objects (which you want to iterate). So first let's remove the assignment to an array, and instead step into the JSON and extract the object that contains your objects that you want:

```ts
.map((res:Response) => res.json().data)
```

This means you end up with an object with your objects. Since object cannot be iterated, we need to use a pipe:

```ts
@Pipe({ name: 'keys',  pure: false })
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args?: any[]): any[] {
        // create instance vars to store keys and final output
        let keyArr: any[] = Object.keys(value),
            dataArr = [];

        // loop through the object,
        // pushing values to the return array
        keyArr.forEach((key: any) => {
            dataArr.push(value[key]);
        });

        // return the resulting array
        return dataArr;
    }
}
```

Then apply that pipe in your template:

```html
<tr *ngFor='let champion of champions | keys'>
  <td>{{champion.id}}</td>
  <td>{{champion.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

That should do the trick! :)

As a sidenote, this means your response is not an Array of `Champion`, so assigning it `<Champion[]>` is inaccurate. However your interface is built, you need to make the appropriate changes.

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/qJP9mIJQbxYGFx1klPku?p=preview)

Comment: this way works... but i need to transform the Json in my object, i need to do some operations in a object

Comment: Okay... well your question does not mention that at all, just how to show your data...

Comment: yeah, I thinked this way I could do wherever I need, but don't :/ sorry

Comment: I consider this answer solving your exact issue in the question, so you should consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting of this answer. If you have a new question, you ask a new question where you explain exactly what you want to accomplish ;) I'd be happy to help with that as well :) This should be a separate question where you tell how you want to modify the data before displaying it in the template.

Comment: No problem, happy to help! Just try and state future questions as clearly as possible and you will get the answer(s) you are looking for :)